# Use older version of Office.js for Word add-in?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

Microsoft updated Office.js this week, and a bug in the latest version is causing serious issues for users of my Word add-in.

Is it possible to specify an older version of Office.js?  This seems like basic functionality that should be provided.

I see that it is possible to self host Office.js but Microsoft says that you can't do this for add-ins on App Source and my add-in is available there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone associated with Microsoft posted an answer, but the answer was downvoted and deleted.  :(

I have enough rep to see the deleted answer so I will repeat it:

> The Office.js version cannot be specified.

So you are stuck with the latest version of Office.js and cannot change that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide details about the bug that you are facing after the update was made? If there is a regression we can make the patch/update to address the issue. So far we have not received any other issues - so any information you can share around which API is failing with error info would be great.

Comment: "So far we have not received any other issues - so any information you can share around which API is failing with error info would be great." --> There are 397 open issues on the github office.js site.

Comment: Hi @Gaefan, The open issues on the site are not related to this particular version update and the issues range from questions/feature-asks/bugs. So, equating all open items to a recent version update would not be right. I'm interested in what new issue you are seeing now. Thanks

Comment: Sudhi, I'd appreciate your help with resolving the bug, but this isn't the right place to do that.  This is my bug report, if you can help there: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1794